# Delphi TJSONArray Memory Leaks: Cannot FreeandNil JSON containers/objects

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe6

The image below lists the memory leaks introduced by the following code:

METHOD:

```
    procedure TInformationSource.SetConfig;
var
  vJSONConfigList : TStringList;
  vCurrentFileName : string;
  vDebugString : string;

begin

    if iCJSONByteStream = nil then
      iCJSONByteStream := TBytesStream.Create;

    if vJSONConfigList = nil then
      vJSONConfigList := TStringList.Create;

    for vCurrentFileName in uCInformationSourceConfigFileNames do
    begin

      iCJSONBytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(vCurrentFileName);
      iCJSONAsStr := TFile.ReadAllText(vCurrentFileName);

      fMain.jdInformationSource.JsonText := iCJSONAsStr;
      fMain.jtvInformationSource.LoadJson(false);

      if iCConfigsList = nil then
        iCConfigsList := TStringList.Create;
      if iCJSONData = nil then
        iCJSONData := TJSONArray.Create; // TJSONObject.Create();


      iCJSONConfigData := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(iCJSONBytes , 0) as TJSONObject;

      vDebugString := iCJSONConfigData.ToString;
      iCEndpoint             := GetActiveEndpoint;
      iCHeaderParams         := GetActiveHeaderParams;
      iCActiveAuthParams     := GetActiveAuthParams;
      iCActiveProtocolParams := GetActiveProtocolParams;
      iCActiveSourceName     := GetActiveSourceName;
end;end;
```

DESTRUCTOR OF OBJECT:

```
    destructor TInformationSource.Destroy;
begin

  FreeandNil(iCHeaderParams);         // Okay
  FreeandNil(iCActiveProtocolParams); // Okay
  FreeandNil(iCJSONByteStream);       // Okay
  FreeandNil(iCConfigsList);          // Okay
  FreeandNil(uCInformationSourceConfigFileNames);  //Okay

  //FreeandNil(iCJSONConfigData);      // nil pointer access violation - Why?
  //FreeandNil(iCActiveAuthParams);    // nil pointer access violation - Why?
  //FreeandNil(iCJSONData);            // nil pointer access violation because TJSONArray Virtual base class?
  //FreeandNil(iCAuthPairs);           // nil pointer access violation because TJSONArray Virtual base class?

  inherited;
end;
```

DECLARATIONS:

```
//...
       private
   iCJSONData             : TJSONArray;
    iCAuthPairs            : TJSONArray;
    iCHeaderParams         : TJSONObject;
    iCActiveAuthParams     : TJSONArray;
    iCActiveProtocolParams : TJSONObject;
    iCActiveSourceName     : String;
    iCJSONAsStr : string;
    iCJSONBytes : TBytes;
    iCJSONByteStream : TBytesStream;
    iCConfigsList : TStringList;
    iCJSONConfigData : TJSONObject;
//...
```

[image: Memory leaks caused by the above code]

Now the last 5 FreeandNil statements in the Destructor each deliver an access violation. For the TJSONArray instances my understanding at this time is that either you cannot FreeandNil TJSONArray objects because you cannot construct them with .Create in the first place (the compiler complains that you have instantiated an object from a class with virtual methods) - or else you can only FreeandNil them if they are instantiated using TJSONValue.GetValue. However I am not sure if this is true and if it is I am not sure why ythe difference. See the next paragraph.

TJONValue is a Virtual base class of sealed and therefore unextendable classes TJSONArray and TJSONObject. I am creating instances of the latter objects with calls to TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue and TJSONValue.GetValue where X is the type of value (TJSONArray, TJSONObject) to be returned.

Now it looks like I am getting access violations for FreeandNil on TJSONObject instances created by calls to TObject(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(...,TByteArray)) (which is returning valid values), while I am not getting access violations on TJSONObjects created with calls to TJSONValue.GetValue(keystring);

I do not understand why this is.

Are the TMoveArray leaks associated with the leaked TJSONArray objects as it seems?

And additional question is - how does one free the memory associated with TBytes instance which are instances of the generic TArray where the type constraint is type Bytes? Some of the memory leaks in the image are associated with those also. Or is this done utomatically and therefore does not contribute to the memory leak list below.

Comment: This is code is full of leaks. `SetConfig()` has a local `TStringList` that is not being freed (t is not even being used). The loop is calling `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` for multiple files but is assigning the result to a single reused variable without freeing the previous object each time. I suspect you meant to add `iCJSONConfigData` to `iCJSONData` but forgot to do so. If that is the case, your destructor should NOT be freeing `iCJSONConfigData` since `iCJSONData` owns it, just free `iCJSONData` by itself and it will free the contained objects for you.

Comment: I have activated the leak detection on the FastMM, and in it's current state no leaks are reported.

Comment: "NOT be freeing iCJSONConfigData since iCJSONData owns it, just free iCJSONData by itself " This was indeed part of the problem. 

As was the fact that I had assigned members of the iCJSONConfigData object to the second five objects because they were associated with properties of business objects that just exposed leaf node JSON objects in iCJSONConfig data (which is populated by a large JSON config file). So when I destroyed the second set, I was freeing parts of iCJSONConfig Data that were already freed. 

Thanks heaps Remy.

Comment: What is the status of adding exception handlers to destructors in XE6 and XE7? Is it still a bad idea because the exception handler prevents inherited from being reached?

Comment: So of course in answer to my own question - there of course is no difference between objects instantiated with .GetValue and with ParseJSONValue. I was just freeing TJSONObject and TJSONArray parts/nodes of a TJSONObject instance, then trying to free the entire instance including those again.

Comment: a destructor should never be allowed to raise an exception for any reason. If you code your objects correctly, destructors should always be able to clean up resources that are in a good known state. Nothing should ever be unknown in a destructor.